# Troubles with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following xml file (which contains data about more than 2 gb):

```
<events version="1.0">
    <event time="10998.0" type="actend" person="1" link="link36" actType="home"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="departure" person="1" link="link36" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="1" vehicle="1"  />
....
</events>
```

And for reading and analysing the data I try to use this approach: http://boscoh.com/programming/reading-xml-serially.html

But when I try the namespace thing:

```
nsmap = {}
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(xmL, events=('start-ns')):
  ns, url = elem
  nsmap[ns] = url
print(nsmap)
```

An Error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-6baf583a11d5>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Codezeug/Pypy/01/PlayingAround.py', wdir='C:/Codezeug/Pypy/01')

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Codezeug/Pypy/01/PlayingAround.py", line 22, in <module>
    for event, elem in etree.iterparse(one, events=('start-ns')):

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1218, in iterparse
    pullparser = XMLPullParser(events=events, _parser=parser)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1261, in __init__
    self._parser._setevents(self._events_queue, events)

ValueError: unknown event 's'
```

How does this code work and why does it search for 's'?

Comment: try `('start-ns',)`

Comment: I tried, now I get this Error: ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: If your document does not use any namespaces, it does not make sense to care about `start-ns` events. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a tuple to

```
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(xmL, events=('start-ns',)): # added , to make it a tuple
```

else it will interprete the string as iterable and try each character seperately.

---

Your XML does not contain namespaces:

```
t = """<events version="1.0">
    <event time="10998.0" type="actend" person="1" link="link36" actType="home"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="departure" person="1" link="link36" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="1" vehicle="1"  />
</events>"""

with open("data.xml","w") as f: f.write(t)

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
with open("data.xml") as f:
    for event, elem in etree.iterparse(f, events=('start-ns', )):
        print (event, elem)
```

works but prints nothing - change the xml to one with namespace to get output:

```
t = """<events version="1.0" xmlns:k="some_namespace">
    <event time="10998.0" type="actend" person="1" link="link36" actType="home"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="departure" person="1" link="link36" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="1" vehicle="1"  />
</events>"""
```

Outputs:

```
start-ns ('k', 'some_namespace')
```

Comment: I changed the XML like you said, but I still get the same Error: ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: They are used if you have f.e. two different types of `event` ... that are both named `event` but mean different things (xml with mouse-events and historical-events  - you prefix each with a different namespace to distinguish them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace